# Trigger .click() on a link on mobile view only

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm currently working on a WordPress website with a Table of Contents plugin. All the plugin do is just detect headings and add them to its contents.

What I am trying to achieve on my current website (https://staging.vladesplana.com/planning-center-vlad-test) is that when the Window is at <= 768px, it should simulate a "click" event on the [ Collapse ]  anchor link so that the Contents will be hidden on mobile load and only be Expanded when on Desktop pixels (1280px, etc) load

```
function tocToggle2() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
          document.getElementsByClassName('lwptoc_toggle_label').click();
  }
}

window.onload = tocToggle2;
```

May I know your thoughts or the proper code for this? I mainly just build websites on Elementor and know only basic Javascript.

Tried a few things as well from my searches and on Stack to no avail.

I use Custom CSS & JS plugin to insert CSS and JS codes into my WordPress website so please, no JQueries

EDIT: Corrected some of the codes.

Comment: You want it initially collapsed on mobile and initially expanded on desktop, but otherwise it behaves the same on both?

Comment: Hi @rayhatfield, yes. I want it collapsed on mobile until it is clicked) and expanded on desktop views and will only be hidden when it's clicked.

Comment: Hi @rayhatfield

I have added an answer now :) Thank you so much.

Comment: add some class or id as selector in element on small devices using media query.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I got it.

I just added [0] on this line:
`document.getElementsByClassName('lwptoc_toggle_label')[0].click();`

Source:
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-method-not-working-and-console-returns-an-error-message-in-javascript/#:~:text=click%20is%20not%20a%20function,you%20have%20written%20a%20document](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-method-not-working-and-console-returns-an-error-message-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=click%20is%20not%20a%20function,you%20have%20written%20a%20document).

Since it says there:
If you spelled it correctly then probably this error arises because you are not aware that document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements, not a single element. In order to avoid the error, you need to access a single element and then perform a click().

I checked in the console as well to check if the function is working as intended but it throws an error there.

final code:

```
function tocToggle2() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
          document.getElementsByClassName('lwptoc_toggle_label')[0].click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getElementsByClassName, which will give you a list with every matching element, use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which will return the first one it finds.

The reason your code isn’t working is because you can’t trigger a click on a list of nodes.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, Ray! Just saw this one as well on a document I linked below.